# Map over TypeScript array of 2 different types with a condition for a property that only exists on one Type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have objects of type `A` and `B`. `Items` is an array of `A` and `B`. This code works:

```
type A = {
    foo: string;
    isB: false;
}

type B = {
    bar: string;
    isB: true;
}

type Items = (A | B)[];


const myItems: Items = [
    {
        foo: 'First string';
        isB: false;
    },
    {
        bar: 'Second string';
        isB: true;
    }
]


myItems.map((item, index)=>{
    if(item.isA) {
        return <ComponentA key={index} {...item} />
    }
    return <ComponentB key={index} {...item} />
})
```

Im trying to simplify it so the `isB` property only exists on the `B` type.

```
type A = {
    foo: string;
}

type B = {
    bar: string;
    isB: true;
}

type Items = (A | B)[];


const myItems: Items = [
    {
        foo: 'First string';
    },
    {
        bar: 'Second string';
        isB: true;
    }
]


myItems.map((item, index)=>{
    if(item.isA) {
        return <ComponentA key={index} {...item} />
    }
    return <ComponentB key={index} {...item} />
})
```

However I get an error:

> Property 'isRest' does not exist on type 'A'.

Comment: isA? isB? isRest?

Comment: Could you include code of ComponentA and ComponentB

Comment: @Aleksey please don't unilaterally change the OP's code, we don't know which bits are correct and which aren't.

Comment: `if(item.isA)` is alway false in both cases.

Comment: Have you read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types? That shows various options for discriminating between types in unions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe changed it because it won't even compile in its current state (`;` in object literals)

Comment: @AlekseyL. sure, but it's the OP's job to provide a [mre] (rather than, as appears to have happened here, posting an example they clearly didn't test and walking away) - if you fix it yourself you run the risk of changing what was actually causing their problem.

Comment: OK, I see, you're right

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator) to narrow union to specific type:

```
myItems.map((item, index)=>{
    if('isB' in item) {
        return <ComponentB key={index} {...item} />
    }
    return <ComponentA key={index} {...item} />
})
```

[Palyground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oDMD22BcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYDcKAviiqJFAEILJoYBGAhiQLFy1OhihlCbAqQCuEOo2bhoASWAQAtoU4AKOAB92ASgDaAXTpMAxtgrEomkOq2ECL7Z1Pd0qceJx8KAByADEyEgdhSipgnyh6ABp4v390fkEQgGUIWwoAEyJSGODktPRJaSg5CHjGcyYUJw9CADpNPjBdXTINTUSJAogAD2MEAD4ucTJMKF1gyuDBiT6x1LSSCGBZEgooAB4AYWxNMDsICmAOAGsIEHgkSnyR%20mRW996tV4B6cbr4zbbXYHY6nc6XOC3e6PIbDV5Id6tT6aH5-ejGIA)